# How to store a number with more than 7 decimal places in Java

Tags: java

I'm working on a project that involves geographic coordinates which requires working with numbers like this:
-115.0504490784608

Rounding is not an option. Any ideas?

Comment: `double` can (barely) handle that particular number, but use `BigDecimal` if rounding is not an option for any value.

Comment: While it is certainly possible to use BigDecimal for this and never do rounding, you will get an exception where rounding is required for any representation of a number with a finite amount of fractional digits. Take the result of the calculation `1 / 3` for example (or any other repeating fraction)

Comment: , i think with this problem you could use the Rounding Mode enum,

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest you use BigDecimal in all of your calculations